# SIGABRT with core data object context from AppDelegate in base controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios5, nsmanagedobject

I realise that best practice is to pass an object context down from the first controller in an app but given that my app starts with a navigation controller and has some view controllers which are content only and do not require core data I thought this would be a simpler solution.

Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface CoreDataViewController : UIViewController
- (void)saveContext;

//See ggfela's answer
//@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
//@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (readonly, weak, nonatomic) AppDelegate *appDelegate;
@property (readonly, weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "CoreDataViewController.h"

@implementation CoreDataViewController

@synthesize appDelegate = _appDelegate;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;

-(AppDelegate *)appDelegate
{
    if(!_appDelegate) {
        _appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }

    return _appDelegate;
}

-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if(!_managedObjectContext) {
        _managedObjectContext = self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    }

    return _managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    [self.appDelegate saveContext];
}

@end
```

When I inherit from this class then try to access the managed object context I'm getting a SIGABRT error which I gather means there is probably a memory leak somewhere. I'm pretty new to Objective-C so don't know too much about debugging it.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Also should I really be doing it the other way (i.e. passing context from controller to child controller) and might apple block my app as a result?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the strong attribute, since strong is applied on the setter and you have a read-only property.

Comment: Okay I'm only getting used to strong/weak at the moment. It's all new to a C# programmer to heavily reliant on GC.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. I've changed it (and edited it above) but the error still persists. Could it be anything to do with the app delegate code? (It is just that from the Master Detail template project minus the top method that gives the context to the MasterViewController).

Comment: Just (readonly, nonatomic), weak is also referring to the setter. And you don't need the appDelegate property since you can access it from anywhere.

Comment: Try: _managedObjectContext = [self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext retain];

How I handle this situation is creating a class that handles everything Core Data related and make it a singleton.

Comment: Singleton pattern it is, after reading about it, it looks like a far better way to go.